# How to prevent response lag during Azure autoscale?

Tags: azure, azure-autoscaling-block

I have a REST API, which listens to messages and relays them to botframework bot through direct-line channel. I have rules in place to scale instances, based on chat count.

No trouble there, but during scaling there is a 30 - 60 second timeout handling the message. How can I prevent this?

The API app, bot channel and bot are all in the same service plan, which is scaled out & in. The bot runs in a singleton but the REST api app doesn't, if this has any difference in the matter.

Comment: Bot also answers the delayed question twice and it's now confirmed that there's no resend in the calling system.

Comment: Also, the bot is an custom implementation and not Azure installed version.